# Getting inputs from modules created with insertUI

Tags: r, module, shiny

In my app, there is a module that I will be creating dynamically using `insertUI`. I am trying to find a way to capture the output of this module. In the app below, there is a simple module which consists of a `textInput` element. The server portion returns the value of this `textInput` element and reports that it is active. I am trying to capture this return value.

I have tried to create a `reactiveValues` object to get the output of the modules but this object doesn't seem to be updated when the input is altered. The module code itself is running since I get the message that comes from within the module but the external observe commands that check the `reactiveValues` are only executed when they are re-created. How can I get these values from outside the module

```r
library(shiny)

# a module that only has a text input
moduleUI = function(id){
    ns = NS(id)
    tagList(
        # the module is enclosed within a div with it's own id to allow it's removal
        div(id = id,
            textInput(ns('text'),label = 'text'))
    )
}

# the module simply returns it's input and reports when there is a change
module = function(input,output,session){
    observeEvent(input$text,{
        print('module working')
    })
    return(input$text)
}


# ui is iniated with add/remove buttons
ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton('add','+'),
    actionButton('remove','-')
)

server = function(input, output,session) {
    # number of ui elements already created
    uiCount = reactiveVal(0)

    moduleOuts = reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$add,{
        # count the UI elements created to assign new IDs
        uiCount(uiCount()+1)
        # insert module UI before the add/remove buttons
        insertUI('#add',
                 'beforeBegin',
                 moduleUI(paste0("module",uiCount())))

        # failed attempt to get the output
        moduleOuts[[as.character(uiCount())]] = callModule(module,id = paste0("module",uiCount()))
    })

    observeEvent(input$remove,{
        # if remove button is pressed, remove the UI and reduce the UI count
        removeUI(
            selector = paste0("#module",uiCount())
        )
        uiCount(uiCount()-1)
    })

    # simple test
    observe({
        print(moduleOuts[['1']])
    })

    # test to get all values
    observe({
        seq_len(uiCount()) %>% sapply(function(i){
            print(moduleOuts[[as.character(i)]])
        })
    })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is simple: you need to return the value as a reactive explicitly. `return(reactive(input$text))`

By returning just `input$text`, you're essentially just returning it at one point in time, since `input$text` is just a value. By wrapping it in `reactive()`, you are now returning a reactive expression. The server code has to match that, so I added `()` to the code that accesses this value.

I removed the "simple test" because it was causing an error since that module doesn't exist initially.

```
library(shiny)

# a module that only has a text input
moduleUI = function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  tagList(
    # the module is enclosed within a div with it's own id to allow it's removal
    div(id = id,
        textInput(ns('text'),label = 'text'))
  )
}

# the module simply returns it's input and reports when there is a change
module = function(input,output,session){
  observeEvent(input$text,{
    print('module working')
  })
  return(reactive(input$text))
}


# ui is iniated with add/remove buttons
ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton('add','+'),
  actionButton('remove','-')
)

server = function(input, output,session) {
  # number of ui elements already created
  uiCount = reactiveVal(0)

  moduleOuts = reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$add,{
    # count the UI elements created to assign new IDs
    uiCount(uiCount()+1)
    # insert module UI before the add/remove buttons
    insertUI('#add',
             'beforeBegin',
             moduleUI(paste0("module",uiCount())))

    # failed attempt to get the output
    moduleOuts[[as.character(uiCount())]] = callModule(module,id = paste0("module",uiCount()))
  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    # if remove button is pressed, remove the UI and reduce the UI count
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0("#module",uiCount())
    )
    uiCount(uiCount()-1)
  })

  # test to get all values
  observe({
    seq_len(uiCount()) %>% sapply(function(i){
      print(moduleOuts[[as.character(i)]]())
    })
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the following format worked for me: `input[[paste0(i, "-text")]]`.
Where `i` is the number associated with each UI created with `inserUI`. You can insert the above code in a for loop to get the values of all UI elements created.